# Truncate file open with fopen

Tags: c++, stdio

It's been a long time since I've had to use this... How can I can truncate the file open with `fopen()` at the current file pointer?

I am on Windows if there is no universal solution.

Comment: Get the FD from the FILE * with fileno() and call truncate(). Make sure you have flushed first.

Comment: As I said, it's been a long time. Does a simple fclose() really truncate the file at the current position? Care to enter an answer?

Comment: AFAIR, truncate() comes from POSIX, it is not part of Windows API. It might still work if you use GCC compiler though.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're on Windows, use this:

```
_chsize( fileno(f), size);
```

Or the 64bit version:

```
_chsize_s(_fileno(f), size);
```